# user with role db_datawriter can't select form database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I create new logins and user in my program like this(using sql stored procedures)

```
//new login
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_addlogin", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
string login = radTextBox2.Text;
string password = radTextBox3.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@loginame", login));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@passwd", password));
int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
....
//new user
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_adduser", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
string username = radTextBox1.Text;
string role;
try
{
   switch (radDropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text)
   {
     case "Admin": { role = "db_owner"; break; }
     case "Guest": { role = "db_datareader"; break; }
     case "User": { role = "db_datawriter"; break; }
     default: { this.radLabelElement1.Text = "Role was not chosen!"; return; }
   }
 }
 catch (NullReferenceException) { this.radLabelElement1.Text = "Role was not chosen!"; return; };
 string login = radTextBox2.Text;
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@loginame", login));
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name_in_db", username));
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@grpname", role));
 int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

because I want every user of database to have either all permissions in database for `admin`, only read permissions for `guests` and read/write/update/delete permission for `user` for all tables in database by default.

I thought if `db_owner` allowed to do everything in the database, then db_datawriter allowed to read/write/update/delete data in the database and db_datareader only can read data from database. But when I use login and password for user with db_datawriter role I've got an exception(when I try to view datagrid) - 'the SELECT permission was denied on the object 'Tablename',database 'Databasename',schema 'dbo'...On the other hand user with `db_datareader` role can see it but cant edit(so it works correct).

What's the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want both read and write capabilities then they'll need both db_datawriter and db_datareader roles. db_datawriter only grants write ability because there are use cases where you would want a user to be able to write to the database but not read from it.

Comment: but how to add both this roles to user in sp_adduser procedure?

Comment: You could create another role that has both read and write capabilities. Or you can call sp_addrolemember to add a user to a role to add another role for that user.